# AngularJS Resolve Dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, angular-promise

I am working on an app to allow users to login with different level or access to an application. I added a resolve dependencies to get the list of users. It did return a list of correct users. **How do I pass this object to the controller?** 
I follow a similar example on the website, but my getPrelogin object is always undefined. What did I do wrong?

```
.state('registration.login', {
            url: '/Login',
            resolve: {
                preLoginFactory: 'preLoginFactory',
                getPrelogin: function (preLoginFactory) {
                    var result = preLoginFactory();
                    result.then(function (result) {
                        return result.data.Model.IntroMessage;
                    })
                }

            },
            views: {
                "content@": {
                    templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
                    controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, LoginFactory, getPrelogin, preLoginFactory) {
                        console.log('the value of get pre login')
                        console.log(getPrelogin);
                        $scope.introMessage = getPrelogin;
                        $scope.loginForm = {
                            emailAddress: '',
                            password: '',
                            rememberMe: false,
                            returnUrl: $stateParams.returnUrl,
                            loginFailure: false
                        };
                        $scope.login = function () {
                            var result = LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe);
                            result.then(function (result) {
                                if (result.success) {
                                    if ($location.loginForm.returnUrl !== 'undefined') {
                                        $location.path('/routeOne');
                                    } else {
                                        $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    }//"LoginController"
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolve object `getPrelogin` should return `result` variable, because promise `preLoginFactory` factory does return promise object. By injecting `getPrelogin` inside controller you would directly get data returned from `getPrelogin` which is `result.data.Model.IntroMessage`.

**Code**

```
resolve: {
  preLoginFactory: 'preLoginFactory',
  getPrelogin: function(preLoginFactory) {
      var result = preLoginFactory();
      return result.then(function(response) {
        return response.data.Model.IntroMessage;
      })
  }
},
```

Comment: @JeanB Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You must return your promise:

```
getPrelogin: function (preLoginFactory) {
     var result = preLoginFactory();
     return result.then(function (result) {
         return result.data.Model.IntroMessage;
     })
}
```